# Why does super work with method syntax but not with property syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm running Node 6.9.1.

I define a base object like this:

```
const base = {
  value : 10,
  getFinalValue : function() {
     return this.value
  }
}
```

Now I want to define a modifier for the `getFinalValue` method.

My first attempt was to use the new ES6 `super` keyword:

```
const modifier = Object.create(base)
modifier.getFinalValue = function () {
  return super.getFinalValue() + 20
}
```

However, the code above gives me the following error:

```
> SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
```

The I tried:

```
// With Object.defineProperties within Object.create
const modifier = Object.create(base, {
  getFinalValue : { 
    value : function () {
      return super.getFinalValue() + 20
    }
   }
})

// And with Object.setPrototypeOf

const modifier = {
  getFinalValue : function () {
    return super.getFinalValue() + 20
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(modifier, base)
```

The results were the same error.

However, if I use the new ES6 method syntax:

```
const modifier = {
  getFinalValue() {
    return super.getFinalValue() + 20
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(modifier, base)

modifier.getFinalValue() // 30 (yay!)
```

It works just fine.

If I use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `super`, it works using the property syntax:

```
const modifier = {
  getFinalValue: function () {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getFinalValue.call(this) + 20
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(modifier, base)

modifier.getFinalValue() // 30 (Yay!)
```

Can someone explain to me why does this happen?

P.S.: Yes, I'm aware I'm mixing ES5 and ES6 syntax, but this is on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I use the new ES6 method syntax ... It works just fine.

That's the point. `super` not allowed in regular functions. The [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors) states

> It is a Syntax Error if FormalParameters Contains SuperProperty is true.
>
> It is a Syntax Error if FunctionBody Contains SuperProperty is true.
>
> It is a Syntax Error if FormalParameters Contains SuperCall is true.
>
> It is a Syntax Error if FunctionBody Contains SuperCall is true.

The reason is that only for methods a field is set in the their environment record, that allows the JS engine to resolve the value of `super`. A method declaration is not just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Could you please extend your question with further details or even provide some links beyond the specs? Thank's.